# Storing a calculation in a flask route cache

Tags: python, flask, python-rq, flask-cache

I have a long task that goes off into a python-rq worker queue.

```
@cache.cached(timeout=2592000)
@app.route('/as/<keyword>', methods=['GET'])
@db_session
def auto_suggest(keyword):
    job = q.enqueue(find_keyword, keyword)
    while not job:
        time.sleep(1)
    return jsonify(word=job)
```

I'm using `flask-cache` to try and save the result as its a calculation that only needs to be run once a week at most, once a month is sufficient as well.

The problem I am having is when this runs, it caches the failed response, and not the actual solution.

Any other way to do this? Or suggestion in how I should approach this?

Comment: Why put the job into a queue when you then just wait for the job? And the job object is not the result, which is why `jsonify(word=job)` causes a failed response each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to JSON-encode the `Job` proxy object, not the result of the job. You do want to check for the job *result* here:

```
job = q.enqueue(find_keyword, keyword)
while not job.result:
    time.sleep(1)
return jsonify(word=job.result)
```

This should be cached just fine.

You could instead memoize the result of the `find_keyword` function, using the [`Cache.memoize()` decorator](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#flask.ext.cache.Cache.memoize):

```
@cache.memoize(30 * 24 * 60 * 60)
def find_keyword(keyword):
    # ....
```

This will cache the results of the `find_keyword()` function for a month, based entirely on the `keyword` argument (results for different keywords are cached independently).

One more note: when applying extra decorators to a view function, make sure you put the `@app.route()` decorator *at the top* (to be applied last). Any decorator applied 'later' is ignored as it is not their output that is being registered as the view:

```
@app.route('/as/<keyword>', methods=['GET'])
@cache.cached(timeout=2592000)
@db_session
def auto_suggest(keyword):
    job = q.enqueue(find_keyword, keyword)
    while not job.result:
        time.sleep(1)
    return jsonify(word=job.result)
```

Comment: Quick question regarding the ```cache.memoize```, would I try to cache that within the python rq worker since that is where the find_keyword function is? And will that be saved if the worker restarts for what ever reason?

Comment: @nadermx: It depends on where your cache is located. If you cache in memcached or redis then your cache will survive a restart. If you use the simple cache, then that's only kept in memory of the process, so restarting the worker would see the cache cleared.

Comment: By the way, the `route` decorator should be the outermost.

Comment: @lord63.j: yes, indeed; otherwise the cache decorator is ignored.